PowerPoint Error: "PowerPoint found a problem with content in output.pptx" When Generating Slides Using Python
I'm working on a Python script to generate PowerPoint slides from a JSON file. The script reads slide content from the JSON file, converts MathML to OMML for mathematical equations, and then inserts the content into a PowerPoint template. However, when I try to open the generated output.pptx file, PowerPoint displays an error:
PowerPoint found a problem with content in output.pptx
PowerPoint can attempt to repair the presentation. If you trust the source of this presentation, click Repair.
When I click "Repair," PowerPoint attempts to fix the presentation, but the formatting is often broken, and some content is lost.
Here is the relevant part of my code:

def convert_mathml_to_omml(mathml):
    try:
        tree = etree.fromstring(mathml)
        xslt = etree.parse(r'D:\MOMLP\MOMLP\static\MML2OMML.XSL')
        transform = etree.XSLT(xslt)
        new_dom = transform(tree)
        return new_dom
    except etree.XMLSyntaxError as xml_err:
        print(f"XML Syntax Error: {xml_err}")
    except etree.XSLTParseError as xslt_err:
        print(f"XSLT Parse Error: {xslt_err}")
    except etree.XSLTApplyError as apply_err:
        print(f"XSLT Apply Error: {apply_err}")
    except Exception as err:
        print(f"General Error: {err}")
    return None

def add_slide(prs, title, subtitle=None, content=None):
    try:
        slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[6]
        slide = prs.slides.add_slide(slide_layout)

        title_placeholder = slide.shapes.title
        content_placeholder = slide.placeholders[1]

        title_placeholder.left = Inches(0.5)
        title_placeholder.top = Inches(0.5)
        title_placeholder.width = Inches(9)
        title_placeholder.height = Inches(1.5)

        title_placeholder.text = title
        if subtitle:
            title_placeholder.text += f"\n{subtitle}"

        for paragraph in title_placeholder.text_frame.paragraphs:
            for run in paragraph.runs:
                run.font.size = Pt(15)
                run.font.bold = True

        content_text = []
        mathml_items = []
        if content:
            for item in content:
                if isinstance(item, str):
                    content_text.append(item)
                elif isinstance(item, dict) and 'mathml' in item:
                    mathml_items.append(item['mathml'])

        content_text.append("")

        content_placeholder.left = Inches(1.5)
        content_placeholder.top = Inches(2.0)
        content_placeholder.width = Inches(9)
        content_placeholder.height = Inches(5.5)

        if content_text:
            combined_text = '\n'.join(content_text)
            content_placeholder.text = combined_text

            if mathml_items:
                nsmap = {
                    'a14': "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main",
                    'm': "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math"
                }
                wrapper = etree.Element(
                    '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main}m',
                    nsmap=nsmap
                )
                omml_para = etree.SubElement(
                    wrapper,
                    '{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math}oMathPara'
                )

                for mathml in mathml_items:
                    omml = convert_mathml_to_omml(mathml)
                    if omml is not None:
                        omml_para.append(omml.getroot())

                p = content_placeholder.text_frame.add_paragraph()
                p._element.append(wrapper)
                p = content_placeholder.text_frame.add_paragraph()  

            p = content_placeholder.text_frame.add_paragraph()

        for paragraph in content_placeholder.text_frame.paragraphs:
            for run in paragraph.runs:
                run.font.size = Pt(15)
                run.font.name = 'Calibri'
                run.font.bold = False
    except Exception as err:
        print(f"Error adding slide: {err}")

def main(json_file, template_pptx, output_pptx):
    try:
        prs = Presentation(template_pptx)
        
        with open(json_file, 'r') as file:
            slides = json.load(file)

        for i, slide in enumerate(slides):
            title = slide.get('title', '')
            subtitle = slide.get('subtitle', None)
            content = slide.get('content', [])
            add_slide(prs, title, subtitle, content)
            
            if i == 0:
                title_slide = prs.slides[0]
                title_shape = title_slide.shapes.title
                title_shape.text = title
        
        prs.save(output_pptx)
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
    

Details:

PowerPoint Template: I'm using a custom PowerPoint template (template.pptx).
MathML to OMML Conversion: I'm converting MathML to OMML using an XSLT file (MML2OMML.XSL).
JSON Input: The script reads content from a JSON file and generates slides based on the data.
Error Handling: The script includes error handling, but the generated PPTX still seems to have some corruption issues.

Problem:
Despite the error handling and the content being generated correctly as far as I can tell, PowerPoint reports an issue with the file when attempting to open it. I suspect it might be related to the way I'm embedding the OMML content, but I'm not sure.

What could be causing PowerPoint to throw this error?
Is there a better way to embed MathML/OMML in PowerPoint using Python?
How can I debug or validate the PowerPoint XML to identify the specific issue?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Is the XSL you are using this one or this? At a first glance they look limited to Word only and would need tweaking. Also, I would say that creating side/objects as you do, adds them into an existing .pptx file, while if you want to modify the OOXML you would need to first work on the file as an archive (that is, modify its extension if necessary and open it with an archive manager, then do XSL operations on the xml of the slide)

I would observe that manipulating the XML is an extremely fragile exercise - and this is at the more complex end of the spectrum for doing that.

@OranG.Utan I got this XSL file inside my Microsoft office source folder.

How do you know if it generates XML suitable for injection into the .pptx file?

@MartinPacker I validated the generated OMML against the Office Open XML schema to ensure it conforms to the structure PowerPoint expects and i injected a small parts of the XML into a .pptx file and opened it in PowerPoint to see if it loads correctly and it worked fine then I double-checked all namespaces and elements to make sure they are valid for PowerPoint.
